# HLSL - how does vertex shader's output POSITION0 affect pixel shader's texture mapping uv?

Tags: directx, hlsl, directx-9

It seems POSITION/POSITION0's w devide everything in output struct. thus made pixel shader can do correct perspective mapping.and it cant be removed,otherwise pixel shader wont output anything.

i didn't see any configuration in program code.  Is it a fixed default setting for all devices? or can i customize this setting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the choice to disable the perspective correction in hlsl on any interpolator as find [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb509668(v=vs.85).aspx).

The modifier you want is `noperspective`.